# AWS EC2 BOTO3: Create Instance Tag while Lanuch EC2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I am using below script for launch Instance but is there anyway to provide Tag (instance-name)

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-0cf6b4320f9bf5529', InstanceType='t2.micro', MinCount=1, MaxCount=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by providing a `TagSpecifications` option as detailed in [the official documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html) for the `create_instances` method.

Comment: Please provide more details I couldn't find ```TAGSpecification``` in ```create_instances```

Comment: I also tried it. but not working for me. can you please paste the code.

Comment: If you go to this link: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Subnet.create_instances and scroll down to the *Request Syntax* section, you will see `TagSpecifications`. Or just search for "TagSpecifications" on that page. I'm happy to help point you in the right direction, but I'm not writing your code for you.

Answer (score 0):

See the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.create_instances). There is an example request format.

```
instance = ec2.create_instances(
    ...
    TagSpecifications=[
        {
            'ResourceType': 'client-vpn-endpoint'|'customer-gateway'|'dedicated-host'|'dhcp-options'|'elastic-ip'|'fleet'|'fpga-image'|'host-reservation'|'image'|'instance'|'internet-gateway'|'launch-template'|'natgateway'|'network-acl'|'network-interface'|'reserved-instances'|'route-table'|'security-group'|'snapshot'|'spot-instances-request'|'subnet'|'traffic-mirror-filter'|'traffic-mirror-session'|'traffic-mirror-target'|'transit-gateway'|'transit-gateway-attachment'|'transit-gateway-route-table'|'volume'|'vpc'|'vpc-peering-connection'|'vpn-connection'|'vpn-gateway',
            'Tags': [
                {
                    'Key': 'string',
                    'Value': 'string'
                },
            ]
        },
    ],
    ...
)
```

You can select the resource type and set the tags as you wish.